# Javascript code doesn't work when including externally from file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have my complete php theme that I'm designing and there is another plugin that I am using for a Image Slideshow,

This is the code for my image slideshow,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.photostack.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#photos').photostack({
          speed : 600,
          easeIn : 'easeOutExpo',
          easeOut : 'easeInExpo',
          autoplay : true,
          autoplayTimeout : 2000
        });
      });
    </script>

        <div id="photos">
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_1.jpg" alt="Streetart 1" width="500" height="333" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_2.jpg" alt="Streetart 2" width="500" height="332" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_3.jpg" alt="Streetart 3" width="500" height="332" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_4.jpg" alt="Streetart 4" width="500" height="375" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_5.jpg" alt="Streetart 5" width="500" height="375" />
        </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
```

When I am saving this code in a single file php or html file, the slideshow is working, but when I am 
using this code in the body area of my actual theme then slideshow is not working only the images are displaying statically. 
All the JScript file are linked properly.

This is the code for my main.php file where the slideshow not working,

```
<?php include('header.php') ?>

        <p>Description goes here</p>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.photostack.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#photos').photostack({
          speed : 600,
          easeIn : 'easeOutExpo',
          easeOut : 'easeInExpo',
          autoplay : true,
          autoplayTimeout : 2000
        });
      });
    </script>

        <div id="photos">
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_1.jpg" alt="Streetart 1" width="500" height="333" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_2.jpg" alt="Streetart 2" width="500" height="332" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_3.jpg" alt="Streetart 3" width="500" height="332" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_4.jpg" alt="Streetart 4" width="500" height="375" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_5.jpg" alt="Streetart 5" width="500" height="375" />
        </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

and this is the code for the slideshow.php / slideshow.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.photostack.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#photos').photostack({
          speed : 600,
          easeIn : 'easeOutExpo',
          easeOut : 'easeInExpo',
          autoplay : true,
          autoplayTimeout : 2000
        });
      });
    </script>

        <div id="photos">
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_1.jpg" alt="Streetart 1" width="500" height="333" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_2.jpg" alt="Streetart 2" width="500" height="332" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_3.jpg" alt="Streetart 3" width="500" height="332" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_4.jpg" alt="Streetart 4" width="500" height="375" />
          <img src="plugins/stack/images/sa_m_5.jpg" alt="Streetart 5" width="500" height="375" />
        </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
```

slideshow.php / slideshow.html and my main theme file are all in the same directory, I have no idea why the slideshow is not working when implementing it in my theme file while it is working in a seperate file :/

I have also tried including the slideshow.php in the main file using php but this doesn't work too.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an outdated version of jQuery? 1.3.2 is nearly 5 years old!

Comment: Check flow for external script on that particular page.

Comment: Script includes (external JS files) should go in your header. Can you show the entire HTML page output that fails?

Comment: Since the only difference (that we can see) is the include - header.php - I would look there for any problems.  There may be something in there that causes a conflict or even breaks your markup.

Comment: first of all use latest version of jquery this one is very old.plus try to include the script tag(slideshow) below the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the javascript code before end body tag. Hope this can solve your problem.

For example:

```
<body>  
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/stack/js/jquery.photostack.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photos').photostack({
      speed : 600,
      easeIn : 'easeOutExpo',
      easeOut : 'easeInExpo',
      autoplay : true,
      autoplayTimeout : 2000
    });
  });
</script></body>
```